# NSMutableArray: get a specific object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray`. When I use `NSLog`, this is the output:

```
2012-12-15 17:58:28.849 Splash-it[504:907] (
"Open House New York",
"Boston Athletic Association",
"Autofest Tanzania"
),
```

How can I get the I get an `NSString` with one of these titles (considering that the titles will change, I think I need to use the `objectAtIndex` but I don't think it will work in this case)?

e.g.

```
NSString = @"Boston Athletic Association"
```

Comment: Needless to say, if you pulled up the documentation for [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), which also would have references to the [Collections Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF), you would find your answer pretty quickly. I'd suggest you review those documents.

Comment: ok, but apple docs just chaos, I always avoid them

Comment: "I always avoid them" -- that's a problem. Sometimes the docs are hard to follow, but many of them are quite good, and you need to study them or you will have a very incomplete understanding of Apple's frameworks and coding paradigms.

Comment: I agree with rdelmar (as usual). You're really losing out on the richest source of information available. And, no offense, but Stack Overflow is not your replacement for looking at the docs (or doing a simple google search). People will down vote your questions as "this question does not demonstrate any research effort".

Comment: Ok I understood, i'll pay more attention at the docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`objectAtIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDJBFC) works perfectly well with mutable arrays. Thus, using zero-based index, to get the second object in the array, you would do:

```
NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

With newer versions of Xcode, you can also use this syntax:

```
NSString *string = array[1];
```

Comment: Both yield equal results and work much the same way. There are no security issues to consider.  Much like the string example you gave using @-sign and double quotes could be done using method calls.

Comment: @Alessandro The former is more conventional, offering greater backward compatibility. The latter is a fairly recent convention.